# How to detect mobile phone event in browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

Now i have a HTML5 web app designed to running on mobile devices, Android And IOS. And I'm using Web Audio Api to play sound, and I want to pause playing when there is a call coming. Searched on Google that on Android there is a TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED notification broadcast to Apps when there is a phone call, but i don't know how to handle it using javascript in browser.

Any tips about this problem will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~gcu201/websys/cordova-3.4.0/cordova-amazon-fireos/test/cordova/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/src/android/Device.java

hope it can help !

Comment: thanks a lot, but this java code, could not use in Mobile browser.

Comment: don't you use apache cordova  ?

Comment: I read the cordova doc, find we are not say the same thing, first of all, my webapp can run on any mobile browser, these browsers not support cordova, so I can use it't API.